# is there any advantage to use dns server instead of dns that based on /etc/hosts

Tags: linux, shell-script, dns, resolution, hosts

we have two option to use DNS in our presto cluster

1. use /etc/hosts and set all aliases in hosts files
2. use DNS server ( WIN 2008 server ) , and configure /etc/resolve.conf

the first option is more simple to set , 
but dose we get on both options the same affect?

Comment: How do you plan to distribute updates to the `/etc/hosts` file to all clusters? How is this more simple then modifying the names in a central location? Also, you don't need to use a WIN 2008 server; linux has plenty of DNS options. The logical place to put the DNS server is on the same machine as the DHCP server for your cluster - then you don't even have to change `/etc/resolv.conf`.

Comment: you mentioned - "The logical place to put the DNS server is on the same machine as the DHCP server for your cluster" , can you give article/example for this procedure ?

Comment: Have e.g. a look at [dnsmasq](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dnsmasq) for a simple all-in-one DNS and DHCP solution for a reasonably small cluster (it's also used in home routers etc.). There should be plenty of tutorials with details how to set it up, google and pick one you like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `/etc/hosts`, you need to somehow keep track that all the necessary hostnames are listed in the file, and that the file is up-to-date and free of errors on all the servers.

When using a DNS server, the management of all the hostname information is nicely centralized in one place (the DNS server) and DNS also includes some features that are simply not possible with just a hosts file. Some cluster/failover technologies may rely on those features for 100% correct set-up. (For example, Oracle RAC high-availability database cluster requires a single hostname to point to multiple IP addresses in a round-robin fashion. This can be properly implemented only using a DNS server, not with a hosts file.)

A Windows DNS server is often a part of Active Directory set-up. As such, it is already a pretty critical component in your IT infrastructure and you might already have multiple redundant Active Directory servers: that would make the DNS service very reliable, so there should be very few reasons to avoid it. (But if you're still using Windows 2008 servers in year 2019, perhaps I should not assume that.)